# Python Pandas - Applying function to a list of values for each row

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, apply

I have a table (**df1**) with a list of values (*neig_list*, which is a python list) in each row

| ID | neig_list |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a, b, d |
| 2 | b, e, f, g, h |
| 3 | b, a, j, k |

And a table (**df2**) with entries for those values

| neig | samples | samples_indicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'a' | 3 | 0.5 |
| 'a' | 5 | 0.1 |
| 'b' | 1 | 0.2 |
| 'c' | 15 | 0.5 |
| 'd' | 12 | 0.3 |
| 'a' | 2 | 1 |
| 'e' | 5 | 0.6 |
| 'f' | 6 | 0 |
| 'h' | 6 | 0.5 |

I need to add a column to **df1** getting, for each row, the result for the sum of *samples* x *samples_indicator* for all *neigs* that are contained in the *neig_list* for that row.

For example, for the first row, we would have:

`3*0.5 + 5*0.1 + 1*0.2 + 12*0.3 + 2*1 = 7.8`

| ID | neig_list | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a, b, d | 7.8 |
| 2 | b, e, f, g, h | value |
| 3 | b, a, j, k | value |

Actually, the function is more complicated than that (involves more columns), so ideally I'd like to have a separate function and then apply it to **df1**, based on **df2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate first your math in `df2`:

```
map_ = df2.assign(neig = df2['neig'].str.strip("'"), 
                  calculated = lambda df: df['samples'] * df['samples_indicator'])\
          .groupby('neig')['calculated'].sum()
```

Then, `explode` your first df, and map the values above for `'a'`, `'b'` etc with the calculated formula. Finally, `groupby` and `sum`:

```
df['new_column'] = df['neig_list'].str.split(', ').explode()\
                                  .map(map_)\
                                  .groupby(level=0)\  
                                  .sum()
```

---

```
   ID      neig_list  new_column
0   1        a, b, d         7.8
1   2  b, e, f, g, h         6.2
2   3     b, a, j, k         4.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just define a function that performs the calculations for a given list of `neig`s using `df2` and then just apply it to `neig_list` in `df1`:

```
def result(row):
    return sum([df2['samples'][item]*df2['samples_indicator'][item] for item in row])

df1['new_column'] = df1['neig_list'].apply(result)
```

Note that this requires `neig` to be the index in df2. If it's not, you can do `df2.set_index('neig', inplace=True)` or, if you don't want to modify d2:

```
def result(row):
    return sum([df2.set_index('neig')['samples'][item]*df2.set_index('neig')['samples_indicator'][item] for item in row])
```

and apply it the same way as before.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
def foo(df1, df2):
    return (df1
        .join(df1.assign(neig=df1.neig_list).explode('neig')
            .join(
                df2.assign(new_column=df2.samples * df2.samples_indicator)[['neig','new_column']].groupby('neig').sum(), 
                on='neig')
                .drop(columns=['neig','neig_list']).groupby('ID').sum(), 
            on='ID')
        )
print(foo(df1, df2))
```

Output:

```
   ID        neig_list  new_column
0   1        [a, b, d]         7.8
1   2  [b, e, f, g, h]         6.2
2   3     [b, a, j, k]         4.2
```

Explanation:

- use [`assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add `new_column` as a column to `df2` which, using [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), gets populated with the dot-product of `samples` and `samples_indicator` for the rows in each `neig` group
- use `assign()` to clone the `neig_list` column of `df1` as `neig` and [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to expand each row to one row per item in the `neig` column
- use [`join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) on the above two DataFrame objects to put sample results from `new_column` into each row based on its `neig` value
- use `join()` again with the above DataFrame object (after dropping the `neig` and `neig_list` columns) to add the desired column to the original `df1`.